# Finding the source file containing the definition of functions and variables

Tags: documentation, source

Is it possible to *merge* `find-function` and `find-variable` to a
single `find-function-or-variable` to be able to search both functions and variables at the
same time and going to their definition in the same way as for `find-function` and `find-variable`? 
(possibly with the ability to use 
TAB completion like the original `find-function` and `find-variable` and choosing between two options when a function and a variable bear the same name as remarked by @lawlist).

Comment: This is problematic because some functions and variables bear the same name and the interface would need to be adjusted to then ask the user which one -- or display both.  It is of course doable, but is *perhaps* a larger project than would fit squarely into a standard answer.  However, there are some really bright forum participants who may have a quick modification that would pleasantly surprise me.  I have *grep* on speed-dial, along with `find-function`, `find-variable` and `find-face`.

Comment: @lawlist Is bearing the same name for the functions and variables loaded by `emacs -Q` too frequent?

Comment: I can only think of a few off the top of my head -- `org-agenda-files` -- `buffer-file-name` -- but the answer would be easier to write up if the user is forced to choose which one when presented with two hits/options, rather than displaying both answers in the help-buffer.  The latter is doable, but may be a larger project.

Comment: You can evaluate `(let ((f-and-vs nil)) (mapatoms (lambda (s) (when (and (boundp s) (fboundp s)) (push s f-and-vs)))) f-and-vs)` to get all loaded cases of a symbol being both a function and variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use <kbd>C-h o</kbd> (`describe-symbol`) on Emacs 25, here is the related NEWS info:

> - Changes in Emacs 25.1
>
> ** New doc command `describe-symbol'.  Works for functions, vars, faces, etc...

(It was originally called `describe-function-or-variable` according to [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=824fc04b660631e7ff976a36b7f70f7c3d5fc181).)

Variable and function with the same name can be showed at the same time, for example, `emacs-version`

[image: e.g., query "emacs-version"]

Comment: Thanks xuchunyang, I use 24.5, but it is interesting to know. My main motivation is to go to the definition in the source file as is for `find-function` or `find-variable`.

Comment: I think you can just try to use [Tags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html), Emacs's etags works well for me, you need to create Tags and set `tags-table-list` first, then type `M-.` to use it.

Comment: If anyone wants to use this for 24.x, I've assembled the necessary code from the Emacs 25 sources and placed it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/troyp/93b020c18c6869f4e61f545b72e1421b).